# how to use different port for dns on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, dns

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/resolver.5.html

you should be able to set a different port for dns, ie:

```
 example, 10.0.0.17.55 specifies that the nameserver at 10.0.0.17 uses port 55.
```

but:

```
sh-3.2# networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 185.37.37.37.54
185.37.37.37.54 is not a valid IP address. No changes were saved...
** Error: The parameters were not valid.
```

what gives? how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, may i ask why you want to set a different port for DNS? (some more context might lead to other solutions...)

Comment: hi, my ISP is hijacking traffic on port 53, it has a transparent proxy, so I discovered that I can use any DNS and always get the same results from my isp, Vodafone shame on you

Comment: The issue is that you are using . to true to delimit the paddles and the port - usual this should be :  (although your answer says #)

Comment: tried that as well if I recall correctly. dnsmasq is another program with its own syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the reason for this was that my ISP is filtering DNS requests on port 53. What I did in order to circumvent this hideous action by Vodafone was to install dnsmasq on my mac and add this line to the dnsmasq.conf file:

```
server=208.67.222.222#5353
```

as you can see I'm now happily using open dns' DNS on port 5353